# Apparent Contradiction to Superposition Principle for the Wave Equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, differential-equations

In thinking about the superposition principle I ran into the following question: 
Say we take two known waves:

\begin{align}f(x,t) &= \sin(x-B\cdot t)\\ g(x,t) &= A\cdot x^2 + C\cdot t^2\end{align}

Then, by the superposition principle, their sum should be a solution. But directly applying the wave equation gives a propagation velocity, 
$v = \sqrt{\frac{2A-\sin(x-Bt)}{2C-B^2 \sin(x-Bt)}}$

But this cannot exist for all x and t so the sum cannot be a wave for any $A,B,C$.

Does superpositon actually fail or have I made some other mistake?

Comment: How do you intend $g$ to exist even by itself?

Comment: How is $g(x,t)$ a wave? The superposition principle is the consequence of a mathematical principle: the solutions of *certain types* fo DE add up to form a *full* solution.

Comment: $g$ doesn't satisfy the wave equation.

Comment: Read up on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle

Comment: In your case, $f$ and $g$ cannot be particular solutions to the same DE (the *wave equation*), thus you can't simply add them up.

Comment: @ Gert Why can't g be a particular solution to the wave equation? Direct application of the equation gives a propagation velocity of sqrt(C/A).

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ is to satisfy the equation $v^2\dfrac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}= \dfrac{\partial^2 g}{\partial t^2}$, then $v = \pm\sqrt{C/A}$.  If $f$ is to satisfy the same equation, then $v = \pm B$.  So your equations are (taking one choice for the signs)
\begin{equation*}
f(x,t) = \sin(x-vt)\\
g(x,t) = A(x^2+v^2t^2) = \frac{A}{2}\left[(x+vt)^2+(x-vt)^2\right],
\end{equation*}
where the last form for $g$ just shows how to write it as a superposition of functions moving to the left with speed $v$ and to the right with speed $v$.  If you add these together and substitute them into the wave equation you should find that the sum does in fact satisfy the equation.

(I think your expression for $v$ is upside-down; but if you turn it over and substitute $C = Av^2$ and $B = v$, I think you get $v = v$.)

Comment: Thanks, but why is your substitution valid? Also, plugging them in gives v =abs(v), implying v can only be positive. So the wave can only move to the right.

Comment: Your premise is that g is a wave.  But that's only true if $C = Av^2$, as I showed above.  Similarly, $f$ is only a wave if $B = \pm v$.  (As for abs(v), your expression should strictly speaking have abs(v) on the LHS.)  As an alternative argument, for your expression to come out to be a constant for $v$ (once you've turned it up the right way), you have to have $C = AB^2$, and then abs(v) comes out to be $B$.

Answer (score 0):

The wave function is not arbitrary, it must describe a particular system, i.e. satisfy the Schrodinger equation
$$
  i\hbar \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}+V\psi
$$
Since there is an $i$ on the LHS and no $i$ on the RHS, the wave function cannot be real unless it describes a zero-energy state. Since your time-dependent functions $f(x,t)$ and $g(x,t)$ are real, they can't be solutions to some Schrodinger equations, not to mention to the same equation.

Comment: The OP is talking about solutions to the *wave* equation, not solutions to the *Schrodinger* equation.

Comment: @march Oh, I made a silly mistake...